# Parse values from parentheses and create dictionary in python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a string as `key1(value1) key2(vallue2) key3(value3) key4(value4) key5(value5) k` and would like to extract them into a dictionary as below. I am able to extract values inside and outside of parentheses separately but not able to correlate and create the dictionary in python. Please assist.

```
result = {

    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : "value3",
    "key4" : "value4",
    "key5" : "value5",
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts? Where did you get stuck, what doesn't work for you?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are able to "extract values inside and outside of the parentheses separately"?

Comment: I used below separate regex to get the keys and values separately. but it didn't know how to combine them.  for Keys: re.sub(r"(.*?)\s?\(.*?\)", r"\1", s)  for values: re.findall(r'\(.*?\)',s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##VczNDoIwEATge59i09NuIMTyc/RJCiZGSmzU0ixVwZevlZ48fjOZ8Vu4zq6J0T78zAHYCLHAEeTNbApf5/vTKIKE@oekeleTq2ZHm9Hu6DK6BCk4PbGpJuvGNEaW2L8L6hH1iYaCZAkLCeHZuoCjvQT8WI961YcBpplhBeuAhxJSpP4iIorxCw)

```
import re

s = "key1(value1) key2(vallue2) key3(value3) key4(value4) key5(value5) k"
r = re.findall(r"(\w+)\(([^)]+)", s)

print(dict(zip([x[0] for x in r], [x[1] for x in r])))
```

Result:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'vallue2', 'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4', 'key5': 'value5'}
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

1. Your key-value pairs are apparently delimited with the sequence `') '` between them, so `re.split()` is a nice choice for the first step, with `'\)\s\+'` as a pattern. And remember to first trim the trailing ')', to not corrupt the last value.
2. When you split the string on that regular expression, well, simply iterate through the results list and push each key-value pair into the dictionary. String's `split()` method can be used to split a list item into a key-value pair with `'('` as separator (and maxsplit 1, for you don't expect any more opening parentheses in the item).

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `regex`:

```
import re

s = "key1(value1) key2(value2) key3(value3) key4(value4) key5(value5)"

keys = re.findall(r"([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\(", s)
values = re.findall(r"\(([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\)", s)

result = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}
print(result)

# {'key1': 'value1', 
# 'key2': 'value2',
# 'key3': 'value3', 
# 'key4': 'value4', 
# 'key5': 'value5'}
```